# Django deployment not loading static files in Google app engine

Tags: python, css, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Hi I am trying to deploy django app on Google app engine. My Django app works fine in the locally but in google app engine it is not working. I checked and found that issue is with my static files. My static files are not getting loaded in app engine.

```
********.appspot.com/static/youtube/about.css

Not Found
The requested resource was not found on this server.
```

Its been two days I have trying to follow answers on various forums but none worked for me. I have following in my settings.py

[my settings.py code snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm8gc.png)

```
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'youtube',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sitemaps',
]

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Just for your information, I tried changing STATIC_ROOT to 'static' but didn't work.

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My directory structure:

[my project dir structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4ywP.png)

My HTML file from app youtube, and app directory structure

[about page html file snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbKbe.png)

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'youtube/about.css' %}">
```

My App.yaml

```
runtime: python
env: flex

runtime_config:
    python_version: 3.7
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT yt_analytics.wsgi
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 2
handlers:
  - url: /static
    static_dir: static/
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
```

I have run below command to test on local server and then deploy on Google app engine.

```
python manage.py runserver
python manage.py collectstatic
gcloud app deploy
```

When I run collectstatic command I see it is creating new folder named static inside my project root directory.. i.e. yt_analytics/static

Now I see I have two static directories in my project--

> yt_analytics/static
> yt_analytics/youtube/static

When I ran findstatic command I got:

```
python manage.py findstatic youtube/about.css

Output:
Found 'youtube/about.css' here:
  /home/work/Mirror/Projects/django/ytwebsite/yt_analytics/youtube/static/youtube/about.css
```

Have exhausted all forums and answers before asking this question. I am unable to deploy my app on GAE. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: `DEBUG = False` - django does not and is not supposed to serve neither static, nor media files in this mode. Configure your webserver to serve them.

Comment: You're genius, I served them manually and it worked. Many Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding below code in urls.py after @Ivan Starostin's comment and it worked for me.

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.static import serve

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
]
```

Thanks Ivan for your valuable comment.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: While that technically solves the problem of the static files not loading, the issue with this approach is Django will be serving the static files as opposed to your web server, which from what I can tell on GCP means Nginx. I'm new to GCP and working through all this myself, but generally speaking you don't want to have Django serving your static files.

Comment: on top of that, incorrect syntax. Can you rectify please?