# Django static file images not displayed on IBM Cloud Foundry

Tags: django, ibm-cloud, static-files

I've read some other threads, googled, and tried reading docs but can't find what I'm looking for. I am new to playing with Django, fyi. This same code runs alright on my local and also on pythonanywhere.com

My web app displays a list of 'interests', 'images', and a 'urls'. The 'image' is actually a path to the local image file. The app deploys fine to IBM Cloud Foundry and works, except that the images in static files do not display only the broken image icon displays.

When I deploy, I see in the logs the message "153 static files copied to '/tmp/app/static'" which leads me to believe the collectstatic ran without issue.

from models.py:

```
class Interest(models.Model):
    interest = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    **image = models.ImageField(upload_to='interest/images')**
    url = models.URLField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.interest
```

From the html template:

```
{% extends 'portfolio/base.html' %}

{% block about-class %} about-color-class {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% load static %}

<!-- Interests -->

<section class="interests">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Some of my interests...</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="row-images">
            {% for interest in interests %}
            <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1">
                <a href="{{ interest.url }}"><**img src="{{ interest.image.url }}" alt=""**></a>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Interests End -->
```

From settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

So, I'm not sure what's going on. Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you have debug=False when you have deployed on the server.
The problem is that Django can not serve files/media when you take it out of Debug mode and it is also not a good practice to do so. Rather you should use a webserver like Nginx or apache to server the static and media files.

Although there is a workaround: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67456634/django-deployment-not-loading-static-files-in-google-app-engine)

But I would not recommend using it. Instead, look into serving files using a webserver.

Comment: Yes, I do have debug=False. Agreed that using a webserver seems like what I read elsewhere as the recommendation. I was thinking also I could store the images as blob in the DB since there aren't that many images and they are small.

Comment: Yes you can do that also but its easier to store files as it is. If you are confused on how to deploy then look into, "dockerizing a django application using nginx"

Comment: Yes, I started reading about that and will investigate further. In the mean time, I went ahead and put the images in my google photos and linked them to my site. It's working well until I get the "real" solution in place.